# Array in Magento1

Tags: magento-1.9

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 239

            [order_no] => 787351

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 239
           [order_no] => 787745

        )
)
```

This is my array now i want to print all its value. I have used this code and when there is 1 item in array it works but when there are 2 items in array it does not work.

```
 foreach ($Item as $OrderItem){
        Mage::log("test");
       $amount = item['order_no'];
   }
```

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

Check with below code

```
foreach ($Item as $OrderItem){
    Mage::log("test");
    $amount = $OrderItem['order_no'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($Item as $OrderItem){
        Mage::log("test");
       $amount =  $OrderItem['order_no'];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to print $amount after the foreach and then only the last value will be printed.

Try the following:

```
    $orderItems = array(
        array(
            'id' => 239,
            '787351' => 787351
        ),
        array (
            'id' => 240,
            'order_no' => 787745
        )
    );

    foreach ($orderItems as $orderItem) {
        Mage::log($orderItem['order_no']);
        echo $orderItem['order_no'] . "\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing only one mistake that using parent array instead of sub array please see the correction below

```
$Item = array(
        array(
            'id' => 239,
            'order_no' => 787351
        ),
        array (
            'id' => 240,
            'order_no' => 787745
        )
    );

    foreach ($Item as $OrderItem) {
        echo $OrderItem['order_no'] . "\n";
    }
```